# C++ explicit template specialization of templated constructor of templated class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a class like

```
template <class T>
struct A{
    template <class U>
    A(U u);
};
```

I would like to write an explicit specialization of this for a declaration like

```
A<int>::A(float);
```

In the following test code, if I comment out the specialization, it compiles with g++. Otherwise, it says I have the wrong number of template parameters:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct A{
    template <class U>
    A(T t, U *u){
        *u += U(t);
    }
};

template <>
template <>
A<int>::A<int,float>(int t, float *u){
    *u += float(2*t);
}

int main(){
    float f = 0;
    int i = 1;
    A<int>(i, &f);
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the way, make the parameter `U& u` instead of a pointer. It's safer and easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
template <>
template <>
A<int>::A(int t, float *u){
     *u += float(2*t);
}
```

That seems to work for me.

Comment: Oops, I have a typo there; the U should be float, let me fix that.

Comment: Ok, this seems to work, but it relies on specifying the parameters implicitly. Is this the only way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The definition's function parameter list should match the declaration's.

```
template <>
template <>
A<int>::A<float>(int t, float *u){
    *u += U(2*t);
}
```

Comment: with `U` replaced with float, this compiles with Comeau, but it does not compile with gcc

Comment: I found http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9050 . The problem is specific to constructors.