# Explicit template specialization for templated constructor of templated class

Tags: c++, templates

This question might overlap with this one: [C++ explicit template specialization of templated constructor of templated class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563165/c-explicit-template-specialization-of-templated-constructor-of-templated-class) .
However, I didn't find a solution in that thread.

I have a templated class with templated constructor:

```
template<typename First, typename ... Rest> class var {
    public:
        template<typename T> var(T& t) {
            std::cout << "general" << std::endl;
        }
};
```

But in case this class is instantiated with an object of the same class as parameter (i.e., we'd like to call the copy- (or move-) constructor) something specific should be done. So I tried the following:

```
template<typename First, typename ... Rest> template<> 
var<First, Rest...>::var(var<First, Rest...>& v) {
    std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
}
```

When trying to compile this with g++ 4.6 I get
    error: invalid explicit specialization before ‘>’ token
    error: enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized
    confused by earlier errors, bailing out

I see the problem, I would have to say explicitly for which class I would like to specialize the constructor...

However, I hope it became clear what I want to do. Any ideas how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A template constructor is no copy constructor:

```
template<typename First, typename ... Rest> class var {
    public:
    var() {};
    var(const var& v) {
        std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
    }
    template<typename T>
    var(const T& t) {
        std::cout << "general" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    var<int> i0;
    var<int> i1(i0);
    var<int> i2("Hello");
}
```

Gives

```
copy
general
```

Note: Added some const

Your attempt to specialize a non copy constructor as copy constructor is failing.

12.8:

> A non-template constructor for class X is a copy constructor if its
>   first parameter is of type X&, const X&, volatile X& or const volatile
>   X&, and either there are no other parameters or else all other
>   parameters have default arguments (8.3.6).

Comment: Your answer works fine for the problem stated in the question. It turned out that I did not quite ask what I wanted to ask so there is a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024090/class-with-templated-constructor-as-well-as-copy-and-move-constructor

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specialize templated method without fully specializing the class. It is prohibited by C++ standard.

Typical workaround for that is function/method overloading as Dieter Lücking showed in his answer.

[Also answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097811/c-syntax-for-explicit-specialization-of-a-template-function-in-a-template-clas)