# Why does adding a destructor (even empty) break my struct that uses ref forwarding and collapsing to hold either a ref or copy of a value?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, perfect-forwarding

I am making a class to store a reference to an object if given an lvalue in the constructor and to store a copy if given an rvalue. This is fine and compiles:

```
template <typename obj_t>
struct holder
{
    obj_t obj;

    template <typename obj_ref_t>
    holder(obj_ref_t && o)
        : obj(std::forward<obj_ref_t>(o))
    {}
};

template <typename obj_t>
holder<obj_t> make_held(obj_t && o) {
    return holder<obj_t>(std::forward<obj_t>(o));
}
```

However, when I add a destructor (even an empty one) to the class, I get a compiler error:

```
Invalid instantiation of non-const reference of type "obj_t &" from an rvalue of type "holder<obj_t &>"
```

Why does adding a destructor somehow invoke a constructor call to create a wrapped object out of an already wrapped object?

Answer (score 4):

A constructor template can never be a copy/move constructor

```
template <typename obj_ref_t>
holder(obj_ref_t && o)                  // not a move constuctor
```

When the destructor definition is absent, you're making use of the implicitly defined move constructor for `holder`. The presence of a user defined destructor will suppress this implicit move constructor definition.

Now, the only remaining viable candidate is your converting constructor template above, but that doesn't work if `obj_ref_t` is of type `holder<T>`, this constructor is required to initialize the return value of `make_held`. So a call like this fails

```
auto h = make_held(42);
```

In short, don't define a destructor, or if you have to, define a move constructor.

---

When defining constructor templates like the one you have, be aware that they might be preferred over move constructors in some cases. There are quite a few answers on SO about this, [here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22024322/241631) that describes the problem and has a solution for constraining the constructor template.

---

If you were to compile your code with a C++17 compiler, the above would compile even with a destructor definition because of [guaranteed copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38043447/241631).